# POST value from html select list?

Tags: php

i am trying to send some information to insert-event.php. Every piece of data comes through, except the options listed in my SELECT.

```
     <form action="php/insert-event.php" method="post">
        <select id="skoleDropdown" name="skole"><option hidden>Velg skole</option>"' . $skoleAttributter . '" </select>
        <input type="text" name="Title" placeholder="Tittel" class="ico-title" required></input>
        <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Beskrivelse" class="ico-title" required></input>
        <input type="text" name="pris" placeholder="Pris i NOK" class="ico-title" required></input>
        <input type="date" name="date" class="ico-title" required></input>
        <input type="text" name="img_url" placeholder="Bildelenke" class="ico-title" required></input>
        <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Type arrangement" class="ico-title" required></input>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="LEGG TIL"></input>
     </form>
  </div>';
```

And then i have my insert-event.php:

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['Title'];
$pris = $_POST['pris'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$url = $_POST['img_url'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$school = $_POST['skole'];
$schoolId = '';
$type = $_POST['type'];

switch($school) {
    case 'Campus Brennerviveien';
    $schoolId == 1;
    break;

case 'Campus Vulkan';
    $schoolId == 2;
    break;

case 'Campus Fjerdingen';
    $schoolId == 3;
    break;
}

// Connect and select DB
$connect =  mysqli_connect('localhost', 'chris', 'chris');
if (!$connect) {
    echo 'Not connected';
}

if (!mysqli_select_db($connect, 'eksamen')) {
    echo 'Database not selected';
}

// Submit
$sql = "INSERT INTO events (id, title, description, pris, img_url, date, type, skole_id)
  VALUES (NULL, '$title', '$description', '$pris', '$url', '$date', '$type', '$schoolId')";

if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header("Location:../index.php");
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
}
$connect->close();

?>
```

I think maybe this speaks for itself.

Appreciate help.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the content of `$skoleAttributter`? And options need a value-attribute.

Comment: Also, since you're using `mysqli_*`, you should take advantage of using prepared statements - this will protect your database against SQL injections.

Comment: Thanks, i will take prepared statements into consideration.

Comment: $skoleListe = Skole::all();
   $skoleAttributter = '';


   foreach($skoleListe as $skole)
   {
       $skoleAttributter.= '<option value=""' .$skole['id'] . '">' . $skole['navn'] . '</option>';
   }

Comment: If you could instead show the code in the question, and not the comments. And can you show the actual output from that (if you inspect your HTML, and show exactly how that form is output).

Comment: remove one double quotes after value="

Comment: try my answer @Yuomo

Comment: Who will set value in select tag?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use value attribute for select tag to send data on post page

```
  <select id="skoleDropdown" name="skole">
<option hidden value="Velg skole">Velg skole</option>"' . $skoleAttributter . '" 
</select>
```

then this should be like

```
<form action="php/insert-event.php" method="post">
        <select id="skoleDropdown" name="skole"><option hidden value="Velg skole">Velg skole</option>"' . $skoleAttributter . '" </select>
        <input type="text" name="Title" placeholder="Tittel" class="ico-title" required></input>
        <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Beskrivelse" class="ico-title" required></input>
        <input type="text" name="pris" placeholder="Pris i NOK" class="ico-title" required></input>
        <input type="date" name="date" class="ico-title" required></input>
        <input type="text" name="img_url" placeholder="Bildelenke" class="ico-title" required></input>
        <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Type arrangement" class="ico-title" required></input>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="LEGG TIL"></input>
     </form>
  </div>';
```

And then this will be like this

```
$skoleListe = Skole::all(); 
$skoleAttributter = ''; 
foreach($skoleListe as $skole) 
{
 $skoleAttributter.= '<option value="' .$skole['id'] . '">' . $skole['navn'] . '</option>'; 
}
```

you have added "" this double time remove one from option value attibute

Comment: $skoleListe = Skole::all();
   $skoleAttributter = '';


   foreach($skoleListe as $skole)
   {
       $skoleAttributter.= '<option value=""' .$skole['id'] . '">' . $skole['navn'] . '</option>';
   }

Answer (score 0):

Extra double quotes problem so values is setting empty

```
$skoleAttributter.= '<option value=""' .$skole['id'] . '">' . $skole['navn'] . '</option>';
                                   ^^^
```

change to

```
 $skoleAttributter.= '<option value="' .$skole['id'] . '">' . $skole['navn'] . '</option>';
                                  ^^^^
```

1) And no need switch case because your setting id as a value attribute . so you can directly use it as schoolId

> Try to use prepared statement or pdo to avoid sql injection .

Answer (score 0):

proper method of select is

```
<select name="skole" id="skole">
<option value="test"> option one text here </option>
<option value="test2"> option two text here </option>
</select>
```

when your request to select like

```
$school = $_POST['skole']; ====> $school = 'test'
```

when select have selected then it will gives you the value of option other it can not give any value.

thanks